# Perl Moose extend child class from Parent by Use statement

Tags: perl, moose

I have the following packages and files:

Child.pm

```
package Child;

use Father; # this should automatically extends Father also

has 'name' => (is => 'rw', default => "Harry");

1;
```

Father.pm

```
package Father;

use Moose;

sub import {
    my ($class, @args) = @_;
    my ($caller, $script) = caller;
    my $package = __PACKAGE__;
    {
        no strict 'refs';
        @{"${caller}::ISA"} = ($package, @{"${caller}::ISA"});
        # tried this also
        #eval {"package $caller; use Moose; extends qw($package);1;"}
    }

}

1;
```

test.cgi

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Child;

my $child = Child->new;
print "child name: " . $child->name;
```

I want the package `Child` extends package `Father` automatically.

I put a code in the import function of Father to push to Child module ISA but did not work.

How to make this work, let Father module extends Child module during the import process.

Comment: Perhaps I don't follow what you're trying to do, but is there something wrong with simply using [`extends`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose::Manual::Classes#SUBCLASSING)?

Comment: to use extends "Father"; i have to use before it use Moose; so I am trying to save this line typing

Comment: I would strongly discourage you from this practice.  The line of typing you save you will repay dozens of times over in the future when folks are confused by your excessive cleverness.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [`Moose`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose) keyword [`extends`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose#extends-superclasses) rather than [`use`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use.html):

```
package Child;
use Moose;
extends 'Father';
```

You're only importing the package with `use`, not inheriting from it. What you are trying to do here is a hack, and while you may be able to get it to work, you're making it harder to understand. Particularly for other people who may have to deal with the code as well.

Comment: to use extends "Father"; i have to use before it use Moose; so I am trying to save this line typing

Comment: `Moose` does its magic through `Class::MOP` which really needs to be loaded to be able to do that magic (like being able to declare attributes). If you're not `use`ing it in your class in some way you're not bringing in the functionality Moose needs, and it's just not going to work. Maybe use `Moops` if you want to shake some of the boilerplate?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at some exporting modules, I found [Import::Into](https://metacpan.org/pod/Import::Into), it is very useful and solved the problem.

Here is how I solved the problem:

Child.pm

```
package Child;

use Father; # automatically extends Father also

has 'name' => (is => 'rw', lazy=>1, default => "Harry");

1;
```

Father.pm

```
package Father;

use Moose;
use utf8;

use Import::Into;
use Module::Runtime qw(use_module);

our @EXPORT_MODULES = (
        Moose => [],
    );

sub import {

    my ($class, @args) = @_;

    my ($caller, $script) = caller;

    my $package = __PACKAGE__;

    # ignore calling from child import
    return if ($class ne $package);

    my @modules = @EXPORT_MODULES;

    while (@modules) {
        my $module = shift @modules;
        my $imports = ref($modules[0]) eq 'ARRAY' ? shift @modules : [];
        use_module($module)->import::into($caller, @{$imports});
    }

    {
        no strict 'refs';
        @{"${caller}::ISA"} = ($package, @{"${caller}::ISA"});
    }

}

sub father {
    my $self = shift;
    return "Potter";
}

1;
```

test.cgi

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Child;

my $child = Child->new;
print "child name: " . $child->name, "\n";
print "father name: " . $child->father, "\n";
```

output of test.cgi:

```
child name: Harry
father name: Potter
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
#Father.pm
use Moose;
extends 'Father';

package Father;
...;
1;
__END__
```

to get rid of all the "extra code".